# Buttons custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, cell

I have a costoum cell with a button. I want to be able to change the button's image when press it. I was trying this but i dont get the desired result.

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
BOOL isTheObjectThere = [self.favoriteArry containsObject:self.tableData[indexPath.row]];
        if (isTheObjectThere==TRUE) {
            cell.favBtn.hidden = NO;
           [cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.favBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell.favBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(favoriteBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}
else {
            cell.favBtn.hidden = NO;
            [cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourites_Green@3x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.favBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell.favBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(unfavoriteBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
        }
```

and :

```
-(void)favoriteBtn:(UIButton*)sender
{
        if ([cell.favBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_selected.png"]]){
        [cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourites_Green@3x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

    else  if ([cell.favBtn.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourites_Green@3x.png"]]){
        [cell.favBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

Comment: You should easily be able to solve this with the debugger. My hunch is that you can not use `isEqual` the way you are using it. Better to keep a copy of the images as local properties then you can just compare pointers.

Comment: the ideea is that the image is changing , but not in the right cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be something like the following:

in your **cellForRow**:

```
[cell.favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

in your **favButtonTapped**:

```
if ([self.favoriteArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [self.favoriteArray removeObject:indexPath];
    // sender setImage...
} else {
    [self.favoriteArray addObject:indexPath];
    // sender setImage...
}
```

good luck :)